# Using multiply in doctrine DQL Order by clasuse

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

I am using doctrine 2.1 DQL
and i want to get a table data with order-by like this:

```
SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY u.s * u.t
```

s and t are two mapped column fields on User.

But i am getting QueryException.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: forgot to mention that it is DQL.

Answer (score 6):

this should do the trick:

```
SELECT u, (u.s * u.t) AS multiplication FROM User u ORDER BY multiplication
```

Comment: Change it to 

SELECT u, (u.s * u.t) AS HIDDEN multiplication FROM User u ORDER BY multiplication

and it works with entities containing one/many to one/many relations as well.

Comment: `->orderBy(new Expr\OrderBy('u.s * u.t'))`

works too, maybe it help someone=)